# How do I convert an .img file to vhd?

Tags: linux, virtualization, vhd, hyper-v, qemu

I have an image file (linux based image) and want to convert it to VHD so that it can be used to create hyper-V VMs.

I used "qemu-img convert" to convert raw to vpc format, but vpc doesnt work for hyper-V and vhd is not supported by "qemu-img convert".

**What would be the right way to do this?**

The image only has one partition:

```
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.8kB  4295MB  4295MB  primary  ext3         boot
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[VhdTool](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vhdtool/) should be able to do the conversion.

```
vhdtool.exe /convert myimage.raw
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. However the command doesnt create a new vhd, but appends a footer at the end of the existing image file. I just have to rename the file to .vhd so that it is recognized by the hyper-v vm creation wizard.

Comment: Also, vhdtool.exe has a prerequisite of windows server OS/NTFS. I was wondering if there is any similar tool (raw to vhd) that can be used on a linux machine?

Comment: I'm not aware of one. But since the destination hypervisor is Hyper-V, this shouldn't be much of a problem. :)

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: @apple16 Yep, it's dead. Microsoft yanked it for some reason. Though copies can still be found with a careful web search, I think it best not to link to any such URLs as they may also change over time, and this one can also be fed to the Wayback Machine if necessary.

Comment: Found this: http://superuser.com/questions/410940/how-to-create-vhd-disk-image-from-a-linux-live-system

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure for how long this has been the case, but since this is the #1 search result for this question, I'll answer it currently. VHD is currently supported by qemu-img.  The argument for VHD is vpc.  This was found here http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/ch_converting.html

In case link breaks, here's a copy/past

Converting images from one format to another is generally straightforward.
 qemu-img convert: raw, qcow2, VDI, VMDK

The qemu-img convert command can do conversion between multiple formats, including raw, qcow2, VDI (VirtualBox), VMDK (VMWare) and VHD (Hyper-V).
Table 7.1. qemu-img format strings

```
**Image format**    **Argument to qemu-img**
raw                     raw
qcow2                   qcow2
VDI (VirtualBox)        vdi
VMDK (VMWare)           vmdk
VHD (Hyper-V)           vpc
```

This example will convert a raw image file named centos63.dsk to a qcow2 image file.

```
$ qemu-img convert -f raw -O qcow2 centos64.dsk centos64.qcow2
```

To convert from vmdk to raw, you would do:

```
$ qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O raw centos64.vmdk centos64.img
```

Note

The -f format flag is optional. If omitted, qemu-img will try to infer the image format.

VBoxManage: VDI (VirtualBox) to raw

If you've created a VDI image using VirtualBox, you can convert it to raw format using the VBoxManage command-line tool that ships with VirtualBox. On Mac OS X, VirtualBox stores images by default in the ~/VirtualBox VMs/ directory. The following example creates a raw image in the current directory from a VirtualBox VDI image.

$ VBoxManage clonehd ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/fedora18.vdi fedora18.img --format raw

Answer (score 4):

As indicated above by [apple16](https://superuser.com/users/126471/apple16) there is a quite similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/410940/how-to-create-vhd-disk-image-from-a-linux-live-system) that circumvents the problem that VhdTool seems not available anymore. Virtualbox comes with a tool called "VBoxManage" which works just perfect. Provided you've got a plain image file of your disk using e.g. `dd`, you can do this:

`VBoxManage convertfromraw myfile.dd myfile.vhd --format VHD`

Answer (score 4):

if anyone is still interested of converting raw disk image to vhd, use the following command:

```
qemu>qemu-img.exe convert e:\src.img -O vpc -o subformat=dynamic f:\dst.vhd
```

Don't forget to change presented filenames to your ones.

Comment: This worked for me. However the device that I was using required the VHD image to be created with `-o subformat=fixed` instead of `dynamic`. `dynamic` is the default.