# How to create a virtual machine from a .img disk image?

Tags: virtual-machine, disk-image, stripe

I downloaded a [disk image](https://stripe.com/blog/capture-the-flag-wrap-up) used for a wargame hosted by stripe, but I cant figure out how to create a virtual machine from this image.
I'm using virtualbox, but I could use another tool if it would be easier

Comment: See also [How do I convert an .img file to vhd?](https://superuser.com/questions/452720/how-do-i-convert-an-img-file-to-vhd)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the solution, VirtualBox has a tool to create the .vdi from .img:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw image.img virtual_disk.vdi
```

Comment: Note that for use with Hyper-V you want to use `... virtual_disk.vhd -format VHD`, so you can mount it as virtual hard disk rather than as DVD media. With that change this works perfectly in 2022 still, using VirtualBox 6 and Hyper-V 10, and avoids having to use untrusted close sourced converter tools that inject who-knows-what as part of the conversion.

Comment: For anyone on Windows getting `'VBoxManage' is not recognized`, try running from `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` or adding the folder to your path.

Answer (score 1):

***For VMWare***
I found a simple but complete freeware tool [here](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter)
Use it to convert `img` to `vmdk` and create a new virtual machine manually within WMWare and set your `vmdk` file as virtual disk.

Answer (score 0):

stripe-ctf-server-ubuntu-10.04-lucid-amd64-20120427-0108.img.tar

> Burn the image to a dvd or mount the img, and then boot from it.

You can now install it into a VirtualBox VM.
Follow the steps in the link below.

[The Beginner’s Guide to Creating Virtual Machines with VirtualBox](http://lifehacker.com/5204434/the-beginners-guide-to-creating-virtual-machines-with-virtualbox)

> Make sure "Mount CD/DVD Drive" is checked. If you're going to install
>   your virtual system from a boot CD or DVD, put it in your computer's
>   drive, then select "Host CD/DVD Drive." If you're using a downloaded
>   or custom-made ISO file, select "ISO Image file," hit the folder icon
>   to the right of the drop-down box, and then hit the "Add" button and
>   browse for the ISO you're using. Once you've added an ISO file to this
>   menu, you can mount it in any virtual machine you're running at any
>   time

Answer (score 0):

Ive used [IMGtoISO](http://www.imgtoiso.com/) and have been pleased with it.  Its free and easy to use.  Plus the ISO format is more compatible with more applications.

Comment: I don't it is an img verses iso issue, I think the image I have is of a full system and not an install disk.

Comment: ISO images are read-only though.