# Running pi-top OS Polaris on a Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso-image, img

I am trying to run the OS found on the Pi-Top in VirtualBox (the OS can be downloaded here https://www.pi-top.com/products/os). However, said OS is available only in a .zip format, which then unpacks into a .img, which cannot be opened in VirtualBox.

I have tried using the steps outlined here ([How to create a virtual machine from a .img disk image?](https://superuser.com/questions/468043/how-to-create-a-virtual-machine-from-a-img-disk-image)) but to no avail; it always fails to find a bootable medium.

I have tried using IMGtoISO, but that also fails. I recently tried mounting the OS in windows 10, but that gave me the error "disk image file is corrupted." The thing is, I know the img does actually work; I have used it to flash SD cards with the OS numerous times, and it always boots on the pi-tops themselves whenever I then power them on. The OS runs with (relatively) few problems on the pi-tops, but I cannot get it to run in a VM.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong or misunderstanding the file types involved (I am relatively new to using VMs, I will admit), but I can't figure out what to do.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: pi-top runs on the Raspberry Pi board, which is a completely different architecture (ARM) than your Windows (Intel x86_64) computer running VirtualBox. 
In order to run an OS designed for a different CPU architecture, you'd need to use an emulator like QEMU that can emulate the Pi's CPU.  Sourceforge offers a tool:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/

Comment: Instructions for QEMU are here: https://www.pcsteps.com/1199-raspberry-pi-emulation-for-windows-qemu/

Comment: @essjae I was able to get regular pi OS to work, but every time I try to run pi-top OS I get this error https://ibb.co/WK0BXVy

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with QEMU or pi-Top to give you much more help.