# Use a .img image as a read-only disk or Optical drive in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning, iso-image, disk-image

I have read [How to create a virtual machine from a .img disk image?](https://superuser.com/questions/468043/how-to-create-a-virtual-machine-from-a-img-disk-image) but here the goal is slightly different.

With a VirtualBox machine, I know how to:

- add a .vdi disk
- mount a .iso as a (read-only) Optical Drive
- convert a vdi => img and vdi => img with `VBoxManage internalcommands converttoraw test.vdi test.img` and `VBoxManage convertfromraw --format VDI test.img test.vdi`

**Question: how to mount a .img as a read-only disk in VirtualBox, and boot on it?**

Important: *without* having to rewrite a new .vdi file from the .img file, because my .img are often 50 GB large, so I'd like to avoid to rewrite everything with `VBoxManage convertfromraw` and avoid using 100 GB instead of 50 GB.

Example situation: you have an internal disk with Linux on partition sda3. You create an image from another Linux with `dd if=/dev/sda3 of=output.img`. Now I would like to temporarily run (read-only) this Linux installation from `output.img` in VirtualBox.

Comment: _Maybe_ you could wrap it in a VMDK file without rewriting? But I'm not sure about the read-only part. Optical drive won't work I think, because optical disks need an ISO-9660 or UDF filesystem.