# Convert Linux box to Hyper-V VM -- disk2vhd fails

Tags: hyper-v, disk2vhd

We've got a RHES machine that uses a single disk.  Not being a Linux guy, I can only tell you that when the disk is inspected within WinPE, I see a 112MB partition (with no volume), and a 499.9GB partition with a volume that seems to be empty.  I can't disk2vhd the 112MB part, even in WinPE (error snapshotting).  disk2vhd the 2nd partition creates a non-bootable VHD.  I tried dd for win, and vhdtool, without success (no bootable partition).

I need to convert this machine to virtual, as we need to repurpose the physical box.  Can anybody suggest how to get it working as a VM in Hyper-V.

Comment: You won't be able to do this using disk2vhd as that's a Windows tool, and won't recognize the filesystems used.  Here's a post about [creating a VHD disk image](http://superuser.com/questions/410940/how-to-create-vhd-disk-image-from-a-linux-live-system) . . .

Comment: @ernie: That article refers to a live Linux.  Mine's isn't - it can be, but doesn't have to be.  I was hoping running a windows program with the Linux disk attached as an external disk

Comment: That article's not actually referring to making the Linux live environment virtual - they use a live environment to make a `dd` clone of the disk.  You might be able to follow the same steps as in that article using `dd` for Windows.  You wouldn't be able to do step 3, so the image will be the full 500 GB, but you could use the windows `VBoxManage` to convert the raw image to a VHD.