# Create image from debian box and move to Azure

Tags: debian, azure

`Linux ariel 2.6.26-2-amd64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 19 00:37:36 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

We have a precious Hetzner Debian Lenny box and need to deploy it to Azure.

Is there a way to take an image of the box and install into an azure VM?

It contains an old python version, old custom python code, rabbitMQ & memcached that cannot be separately deployed today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very much a summary of the post as linked bellow:

Shut down you debian box and boot a live linux on it (e.g. knoppix or ubuntu live cd)

Image the disk using dd and pipe the data through ssh, for example like this (whereby /dev/hdX is the devicenode of the physical HD you debian is installed on, and myserver is another box with enough storage to do your conversions on)

```
 $ dd if=/dev/hdX bs=4k conv=noerror,sync | ssh -c blowfish myuser@myserver 'dd of=myfile.dd'
```

Create the VHD image using VBoxManage

```
 $ VBoxManage convertfromraw myfile.dd myfile.vhd --format VHD
```

But as pointed out, this is a brief summary of a similar answer as linked here

[How to create VHD disk image from a Linux live system?](https://superuser.com/questions/410940/how-to-create-vhd-disk-image-from-a-linux-live-system)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Check, will amend my post