# Self-created VHD image file won't boot in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I've got an old small form factor PC (x86). It boots from a CF card. I'd like to develop software for it but I don't want to use it for debugging since I might brick it. This is why I've tried creating a virtual machine from it. First, I compied the card content using `dd` into a raw image file. Then I used the VirtualBox's tool VirtualManager to convert it into a virtual hard drive (vhd). Following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/410940/how-to-create-vhd-disk-image-from-a-linux-live-system) guide.

I can mount the raw image file in Linux and read from it as well as I can use the vhd file as Secondary Master device attached to an existing Virtual Machine - but I can't boot from it. This it the error I get:

> FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.

How can find out what VirtualBox is expecting from the vhd provided that I have to specify certain option for the image conversion?

Checking the log files for the VM didn't help either.

Comment: SD or CF? Different technologies. Did you copy the MBR too?

Comment: It's definitely CF and yes that's a good question about the MBR. I wasn't really taking care of that but since VirtualBox DOES recognize it as a drive I suppose it is compied as well, isn't it. All I did to get the raw image was `dd if=/dev/sdbX of=~/myimage.img`

Comment: OK I repeated it and it turns out I indeed forgot to copy the MBR. Now it's working as expected. [AthomSfere](http://superuser.com/users/208421/athomsfere), if you could create an answer from your comment (one liner is enough) then I will accept it as the right answer.

Comment: Glad it helped ;)