# Disk2vhd.exe not showing a connected disk

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, vhd, disk2vhd

I have a weird problem on Disk2vhd.exe, while the disk is connected via a SATA cable for sure (That I can boot it without touching the computer lid proves it) and also the disk is recognized in Disk Management, the disk is not recognized in Disk2vhd.exe.

I'm not sure if it's related or not that the disk is not Windows but a Linux (ubuntu 20.04) system, but I heard that hyper-v can boot Ubuntu/Linux so it shouldn't be the problem, I guess. So now I have no idea what can I try. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Disk2vhd is a Windows product. Which disk are you trying to virtualize? See [link](https://superuser.com/questions/410940/how-to-create-vhd-disk-image-from-a-linux-live-system).

Comment: What do you mean by "which disk"? It's just an Ubuntu disk as I described, and it's not a live Linux, just a normal Linux just like the Windows environment, that's why I have no idea why Windows doesn't recognize the completely normal disk. Since I need to run the created VM on Windows's Hyper-V, and Disk2vhd is primarily for Hyper-V uses, I thought it'd be better to use the natively supported option, Disk2vhd. I'm skeptical of that a created VHD from the `dd` way or any within-Linux way for sure would work on Hyper-V.

Comment: The "Disk 0" is the Linux disk, if you're asking about that. You can see that the Disk2vhd  screen right side is not showing the 223.07gb partition.

Comment: You certainly don't want to virtualize Disk 0, which contains your EFI boot code. You probably want to do only the Linux partition. Which virtualization product do you intend to use with the virtual disk that you will create?

Comment: I'm going to use it on Windows 10 Pro's Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

You wish to clone the Linux partition into a VHD file.
A possible procedure to do that is as follows:

- Create a VHD file of the right size (or slightly larger)
  in Device Manager, Action menu, select Create VHD.
  This creates a new virtual disk in Windows.
  See the Microsoft article
  [Create a VHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/manage-virtual-hard-disks#create-a-vhd).
- Clone the Linux partition to the new (virtual) disk using a third-party
  product that you will install in Windows. Possible candidates are
  [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/download.html)
  or
  [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree).
- Dismount the VHD from Device Manager.